# List data on the screen

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, array.prototype.map

I would like to use the map function in my agents variable but it is not available, can anyone tell me why?

code below:

```
axios(config).then(function (response) {
      agents = response.data;
      console.log('agents', agents);
    });
    // (agents.map) map function is not available here
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: is `response.data` an array?

Comment: No, I would like to know why I cannot use .map() in my variable agents

Comment: Yes, is an Array Of Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is async in nature. So whatever modification you do inside `.then` the function will only reflect inside the same scope.

So, whatever you want to do with the agent's value that you are receiving from API call should be done inside the `then` function only.

```
let agents = [];
axios(config).then(function(response) {
  agents = response.data;
  console.log("agents", agents);
  const mapAgents = agents.map(a => a.someProperty);
  console.log(mapAgents);
  // end of scope for the agent's value, it won't be accessible outside.
});
console.log(agents); // outputs []
// value of agent's won't be accessible here due to async nature. This line will get executed first and then.
```

---

### async-await

If you wish to perform some action in a synchronous fashion. You can achieve it using `async-await`, it makes the inside of the function synchronous while keeping the execution of function as asynchronous.

```
const getAgents = async function() {
  let agents = []
  const res = await axios(config) // thread will wait till the api call is completed
  agents = res.data
  // perform your action here
}

getAgents(); // this will now become asynchronous
```

You can learn more about the Javascript async nature, [here](https://javascript.info/async).

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, the code returns "agents.map is not a function" because the agents variable is inside the callback function(response){ ... } supplied to .then(). So it can not be accessible outside.

Comment: so how can i do to turn it accessible outside?

Comment: @nithin_cs so how can i do to turn it accessible outside?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I have updated my answer with one more example. You can have a look at it.

Comment: @paulo Rodrigues, vinayak has updated the answer which is the right way of accessing the variable outside